# How can I dynamically instance an Object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to build a factory class that will feed me singleton-ized instances of different DbContexts.

The main idea is to have a `Dictionary<Type,DbContext>`that will hold all the instances I need , and a `GetDbContext(Type type)` method that looks up type in the dictionary and returns it if it already exists. If it doesn't it should create a new Type(), and add it to the corresponding dictionary.

I have no idea how to do `contexts.Add(type, new type());`

```
public class DbContextFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, DbContext> _contexts;
    private static DbContextFactory _instance;

    private DbContextFactory()
    {
        _contexts= new Dictionary<Type, DbContext>();
    }

    public static DbContextFactory GetFactory()
    {
        return _instance ?? (_instance = new DbContextFactory());
    }

    public DbContext GetDbContext(Type type)
    {
        if (type.BaseType != typeof(DbContext))
            throw new ArgumentException("Type is not a DbContext type");

        if (!_contexts.ContainsKey(type))
            _contexts.Add(type, new type()); //<--THIS is what I have now Idea how to do

        return _contexts[type];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a generic method:

```
public DbContext GetDbContext<T>() where T : new()
{
    if (typeof(T).BaseType != typeof(DbContext))
        throw new ArgumentException("Type is not a DbContext type");

    if (!_contexts.ContainsKey(type))
        _contexts.Add(typeof(T), new T());

    return _contexts[type];
}
```

Comment: `type` is undefined.  I think you meant `typeof(T)`.

Comment: @Guffa Yeap, thats the simplest way to do it alright. But whats the where T: New() part? I've never seen that before

Comment: And what would happen if instead of saying `where T: new()` I say `T: DbContext` wouldn't I be checking for the correct type in there?

Comment: @Me UTFG: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx Explains it all. :)

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Yes, I missed changing that one.

Comment: @DavidSarmiento: The `where T : new()` makes sure that the type has a parameterless constructor, so that you can create new instances that way. You can also add the constraint for the `DbContext` type: `where T : DbContext, new()`. The `new()` is still needed, because inheriting `DbContext` doesn't require that the class has a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can create C# classes by using an [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx).  One method is the [.CreateInstance(Type type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx).

```
MyClassBase myClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass)) as MyClass;
```

However with a DbContext, you will most likely want to pass in a Connection string so use the [.CreateInstance(Type type, params Object[] args)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx)

```
DbContext myContext = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass),
  "ConnectionString") as DbContext;
```

Or as a Generic method:

```
if (!_contexts.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
  _contexts.Add(typeof(T),
    (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), "ConnectionString");
```